# Saving data online for IOS

Tags: ios, database, xcode, save

I'm new to IOS (Xcode) programming and have been searching information about the online storage of data. So far I came across Core Data and SQLLite. However every search results into a storage file on the device itself. I want to make an app that stores routes with the Google Maps API. Because eventually there will be a lot of routes I think it is going to take a lot of storage, even though it is saved as url. I am using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg&feature=youtube_gdata

Within those routes people can post messages on the route it's wall, so that data has to be saved too.

I am used to websites using phpmyadmin with tables for example or Java and postgressql/mysql. Is there anything like that for IOS and if so what is the best approach for this? Core Data?

Comment: I think you have two options - a preconfigured service such as Parse, or setting up a webserver with database and your own api to GET and POST to the database for example http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-create-your-own-ios-web-api/

Comment: Is this the way an app like whatsapp also saves it's messages data?

Comment: Knightsy's comment is a good one! @DaViDa, whatsapp would need to cache messages locally (yes probably via Core Data) so you can read them without online connection. You would use Knightsy's approach to simply pull down data or post up to save online, and for this you would typically pull/post as JSON data (in this situation the web API would do all the work, i.e. it wouldn't be done 'app side').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to learn about [restful web services](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069). If you are familiar with server side scripting languages like php, then you can create web service for each operation. Here is a good [tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) for creating rest api.

Lets say you want to save chat data from iOS app to server. Here is what will happen.

**Client Side** (iOS app): Your app will make a request (hit a url ) e.g abc.com/savechat. With this request, your app will "POST" data along with request. e.g sender name, receiver name, message body and time etc. Then server can send response e.g. a success message back to client.

**Server Side**: Server will perform data operations like storing data and send a response back to client.

For processing web services (JSON) on app side either use libraries like [Alamofire](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/1.2.3/) for Swift and  [AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.4/) for Objective C.